# R shiny: read csv a file in UI

Tags: r, shiny

**Context**

I built a shiny app in R that i can run as i want. It means i can insert `read.csv` before UI and then use the file loaded in R in the UI. Now i need to create a shortcut in desktop so i need to insert the `read.csv` in the UI. But i can't insert a read.csv in the UI. So i need to know how can i load a file and use it in UI so i can run `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\R.exe" -e shiny::runApp('C:/Users/Desktop/Cal_pro')`

In the `Cal_pro` folder i put my `ui.R` and `server.R`

Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: if my inference is correct, perhaps you can pass _csv_ file as an argument as : `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\R.exe" -e shiny::runApp('C:/Users/Desktop/Cal_pro') "C:\Users\Desktop\Cal_pro\input.csv"` and then `args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE); read.csv(args)` for reading file

Comment: Where do i have to put the args ?

Comment: You can use this `args` inside your `ui.R` / `server.R` / `app.R` file wherever csv is required

Comment: i added `args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE) 
modele_prev <- read.csv(args)` in my ui.R before the ui <- function ... but i get error argument 'description' incorrect

Comment: try printing `args` and check whether input is being received properly, also check the `class(args)` to make sure